# Fast data retrieval in MySQL

Tags: mysql, scalability, large-data

I have a table of users - It contains around  millions of rows (user-id is the primary key).

I just want to retrieve user-id and their joining date.

Using `SELECT user-id, joining-date FROM users` requires lot of time. Is there a fast way to query/retrieve the same data from this table?

Comment: What you gonna do with all millions of names and dates?

Comment: want to send it to a remote server.

Comment: every midnight or early before that time

Comment: if it's rare operation, why do you concern about it's speed?

Comment: millions of rows... estimate..

Comment: I think transfer time to another server would be even worse. Network would be a bottleneck anyway. What's the problem again?

Comment: Have you considered using an incremental replication scheme?

Answer (score -1):

To get the highest speed in such a query, you'd need to use a column-oriented database (like [LucidDB](http://www.luciddb.org/)) or a key-value system (like [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)). Using e.g. LucidDB should give you a [1-2 orders of magnitude](http://pub.eigenbase.org/wiki/LucidDbTpch) performance boost with that kind of query. You don't have to replace MySQL: you can just support this use case arround